# How to sum based off index vector

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I have 3 vectors - a sum vector, a contribution vector, and a value vector. I want to sum the value vectors according to their contribution vector and place them in their corresponding index in the sum vector. An example is:

`A = [0;0] (sum vector), B = [0,0,1,1] (contribution vector) C=[20,30,40,10] (value vector)`

Output:
`A = [20+30;40+10]`

Such that the B vector is the same length as C and their corresponding index tell us what position in A to be added to.

I am able to achieve this by a for loop as such:

```
for index,value in enumerate(C):
    A[B[index]]+=value
```

However, as this will be part of my NN model forward loop it will cause significant performance issue. Specifically I was looking for a vector/matrix sorting approach that will be more efficient. In the example above, something that worked efficiently for me was:

```
A=torch.zeros(2,1)
C=C.reshape(2,2)
sum=torch.sum(C,1).reshape(2,1)
A += sum
```

However, I run into issues as it is not always the case that the indexes of A have the same contribution. For example - the case such that `B = [0,0,0,1,1]` and `C=[20,30,40,10,50]`. Is there a function or a strategic way to do this for general cases? Thanks!

Comment: The loop will probably not cause significant performance issues, especially if you use jit https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/jit.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [`index_add_()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.index_add_)

```
A.index_add_(0, B, C)
```

Note that `B` should be of type `torch.long` (it is an index vector), and `C` should be of type `torch.float`, same as the type of `A`.
Moreover, you can use the first `dim` argument to do this summation along different dimensions in case `A` and `C` are multi-dimensional tensors.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed...Thanks!

Comment: Any thoughts on something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55854761/tensor-reduction-based-off-index-vector?

Answer (score 0):

Doing for loop drops the performance to some extent. Suppose the number of unique types in contribution vector is much smaller than the length of B (or C), you can do for loop as below with the assumption `O(num_types)` << O(len_B)`:

```py
num_types = 3
B_len = 5
C_len = B_len

B = torch.randint(0, num_types, size=[B_len,])
"""
>>> B
tensor([2, 1, 1, 0, 0])
"""

C = torch.randint(0, 10, size=[C_len,])
C = C.float()
"""
>>> C
tensor([1., 5., 7., 6., 2.])
"""

# For loop here
A = [torch.sum(C * (torch.eq(B, type).float()) for type in range(num_types)]
# A = [tensor(8.), tensor(12.), tensor(1.)]

# Convert it to torch.tensor
A = torch.stack(A)
# tensor([ 8., 12.,  1.])
```