# Tensor reduction based off index vector

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

As an example, I have 2 tensors: `A = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7]` and `B = [2;3;2]`. The idea is that I want to reduce A based off B - such that B's values represent how to sum A's values- such that `B = [2;3;2]` means the reduced A shall be the sum of the first 2 values, next 3, and last 2: `A' = [(1+2);(3+4+5);(6+7)]`. It is apparent that the sum of B shall always be equal to the length of A. I'm trying to do this as efficiently as possible - preferably specific functions or matrix operations contained within pytorch/python. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum based off index vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55819027/how-to-sum-based-off-index-vector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution.

- First, we create an array of indices `B_idx` with the same size of `A`.
- Then, accumulate (add) all elements in `A` based on the indices `B_idx` using `index_add_`.

```py
A = torch.arange(1, 8) 
B = torch.tensor([2, 3, 2])

B_idx = [idx.repeat(times) for idx, times in zip(torch.arange(len(B)), B)]
B_idx = torch.cat(B_idx) # tensor([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2])

A_sum = torch.zeros_like(B)
A_sum.index_add_(dim=0, index=B_idx, source=A)
print(A_sum) # tensor([ 3, 12, 13])
```