# How to efficiently sum values from a tensor based on indices?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a tensor of values and a tensor of indices:

```
import torch
indices_vals = 5
input_size = 10
output_size = 9
batch_size = 6
my_tensor = torch.rand(batch_size,input_size,indices_vals)
my_indices = torch.tensor([torch.randperm(output_size)[:indices_vals].tolist() for _ in range (input_size)])
print(my_tensor.shape)
print(my_tensor)
print(my_indices.shape)
print(my_indices)
>>>
torch.Size([6, 10, 5])
tensor([[[0.1636, 0.2375, 0.5127, 0.5831, 0.2672],
         [0.0655, 0.6715, 0.2985, 0.2137, 0.6293],
         [0.9522, 0.2506, 0.5669, 0.3462, 0.7513],
         [0.1873, 0.3291, 0.6196, 0.9848, 0.7948],
         [0.0288, 0.1462, 0.3541, 0.9062, 0.0985],
         [0.6837, 0.3336, 0.5584, 0.1463, 0.4188],
         [0.1454, 0.3847, 0.6977, 0.9424, 0.2276],
         [0.6889, 0.7499, 0.5182, 0.6120, 0.5184],
         [0.5230, 0.1946, 0.0222, 0.8145, 0.7094],
         [0.6727, 0.6686, 0.7672, 0.3086, 0.0235]],

        [[0.2809, 0.3987, 0.4391, 0.1588, 0.8547],
         [0.4430, 0.4764, 0.9498, 0.3969, 0.7324],
...
torch.Size([10, 5])
tensor([[0, 6, 4, 3, 7],
        [4, 8, 3, 1, 7],
        [1, 8, 2, 4, 3],
        [5, 6, 1, 4, 8],
        [6, 7, 2, 4, 1],
        [2, 5, 7, 8, 4],
        [2, 7, 6, 8, 0],
        [5, 6, 3, 4, 8],
        [4, 5, 0, 8, 1],
        [8, 6, 2, 3, 7]])
```

Each element in each batch of `my_tensor` has a corresponding index in `my_indices`. At the end, the values from `my_tensor` should sum up based on their index to a final vector of size `(batch_size, output_size)`.

For example, the first row in `my_indices` is `[0, 6, 4, 3, 7]`. This means that the first element in the first row in each of the batches of `my_tensor` (e.g., `0.1636` in the first row) should go to index `0` of the final tensor in the corresponding batch index. The second to last row of `my_indices` is `[4, 5, 0, 8, 1]`, which means that the third element of the second to last row of `my_tensor` should also go to index `0` of the final tensor (this is the summation part). If no indices map to a certain index in the final vector, that index in the final vector should be `0`.

Looking for an efficient way to do this -- currently implementing this as a `for loop` which is ridiculously slow for very large matrices.

**Update:**

[index_add_()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.index_add_) might seem to be a good solution (based on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55819027/how-to-sum-based-off-index-vector)), but I can't figure out how to use this in higher dimension like in my case. Seems like it only works on vectors.